# run gradlew from nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, gradle, child-process, spawn

Trying to run gradlew from nodeJS:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const path = require('path');

function run() {

    var path_dir = path.resolve('./../movies/VanillaApp/android');

    var options = {
        cwd: path_dir
    };

    const ls = spawn('gradlew', ['assembleRelease'], options);

    ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    ls.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });

}



module.exports = {
    run: run
};
```

terminal equavalent:

```
> ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

getting:

```
events.js:154
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn gradlew ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:377:13)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:11)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:449:11)
at startup (node.js:141:18)
at node.js:933:3
```

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to run in with child_process.exec but not with spawn.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon this problem myself and managed to run `gradlew` with `spawn` using the [--project-dir](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html) command-line option:

```
var taskDone = this.async();

grunt.util.spawn({
    cmd: "my/relative/path/gradlew",
    args: ["clean", "--project-dir", "my/relative/path"],
    opts: {
        stdio: "inherit"
    }
}, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        taskDone(false);
    } else {
        taskDone();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-native, so I just created a script folder in my root directory and added a file called cleanBuild.js with the content below:

```
#!/bin/node

const { exec } = require("child_process");
const currentOs = require("./getOs");

const os = currentOs();

//===================================================================
function cleanBuild() {
    console.log("\nCleaning project build...");

    exec(`cd android && ${os === 'darwin' ? './gradlew clean' : 'gradlew clean'} && cd ..`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`\nFailed to clean build: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`\nFailed to clean build: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`\nBuild cleaned successfully: \n${stdout}`);
    });
}

//===================================================================
cleanBuild();
```

Now I can just run it running:

```
node ./scripts/cleanBuild.js
```